# Draw simple objects and animate

Tags: javascript, processing

Make a program in P5.js that runs the following animation:

1. create a canvas with width 400 and height 500 in which, using
   functions, draw 3 robots, 2 of which will be animated so that they 
   move on the screen (see below)
2. the function that draws the robot should only use arguments (and if
   needed variables local to the function), it should not use any global
   variable. The robot has a square head, the body is a rectangle, the arms
   should be horizontal and then vertical, the legs are vertical and it has
   wheels in the feet. The arguments should be the "width" of the head (it is
   the same as the width of the body), the "height" of the body, and the
   coordinates in "x" and "y" of the top left corner of the head. The robot
3. By calling the function that draws the robot create 3 robots, two of
   them of the same size but at different x and y coordinates on the screen,
   the third robot should be larger than the first two and also be
   somewhere else on the screen (no overlaps between the robots).
4. Animate one of the smaller robots and the larger robot by making them
   move left until they hit the extreme of the screen, then they should
   move right until they hit the other extreme of the screen, and so on,
   moving left and right. The small robot moves twice as fast as the large robot.

I can't replicate the robots.

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 500);
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    rect(100, 100, 50, 50);
    line(125, 150, 125, 170);
    rect(100, 170, 50, 100);
    line(80, 170, 170, 170);
    line(80, 170, 80, 270);
    line(170, 170, 170, 270);
    line(100, 270, 100, 370);
    line(150, 270, 150, 370)
    ellipse(150, 370, 15, 15);
    ellipse(100, 370, 15, 15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error? What is your problem? Pleas read the guide how to ask questions and how to create example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: i simply dont know how to do it, im in the middle of a test 

Comment: Is this a homework or some kind of assignment?

Comment: yes, im stuck in the functions

Comment: You must write a class named Robot, and you could create multiple robots and inside this class you could create the animation